# What JavaScript Plugin for Eclipse - I tried Wild Web Developer plugin - Missing JS text

Tags: javascript, eclipse, electron

I'm seeking a modern JavaScript plugin for Eclipse, because that's the only multi-IDE avaiable for free. I'm going to code ElectronJS, and I have never used it before.

I tried to install the packages.
[image]

But when I clone my GitHub repository, I cannot high light any JavaScript code.
HTML code works, but not JavaScript. I don't even know how to run the ElectronJS project in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use Visual Studio Code? Just asking, not trying to answer the question here.

Comment: Make sure to open JavaScript files with the _Generic Text Editor_ (right-click a .js file, _Open With > Other..._, selecting the _Generic Text Editor_ and checking _Use it for all '*.js' files_) to get JavaScript support by  Eclipse Wild Web Developer. That JavaScript files were opened in the plain text editor by mistake, was a [bug that is fixed in the current Eclipse version](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=573902).

Comment: @bub because VS code do not work for me. I ending up where i can't push my commits.

Comment: @howlger Thank you! I'm using STM32CubeIDE editor, which is based on Eclipse 2021-03.

Comment: @howlger So I don't need WWD?

Comment: @howlger By the way! It seems that when I press CTRL+space with a keyword, it don't get reveled. Why?

Comment: @howlger Now it's working. Time to figure out how I can execute ElectronJS application with Eclipse.

Comment: WWD uses the VSCode language server to provide JavaScript support in the Generic Text editor. It seems you also have installed Eclipse WTP JSDT which also provides JavaScript support in a different way. When both, WWD and JSDT are installed, the mentioned, already fixed bug caused JavaScript files to be opened by default in the plain text editor without JavaScript support. If you don't use JavaScript in JSPs and things like that, you might alternatively uninstall JSDT. Anyway, great that it works now.